# How do you use templates to generate dynamic HTML tag attributes in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, html

I am using a Template to Generate HTML Tag Attributes in Meteor, but is seems to be broken. I can't put a template inside an HTML tag in [meteor](http://meteor.com/) and I want to know why.

I'm using [meteor-router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) for routing. Since meteor basically only allows a single layout, I wanted to add a class to the body indicating the current view name, like so:

/client/layout.html:

```
<head>
  <title>Meteor App</title>
</head>

<body {{> body-attributes}}>
  {{renderPage}}
</body>

<template name="body-attributes">data-view-name="{{page}}" class="{{page}}"<template>
```

So that I could do this in /client/layout.js:

```
Template['body-attributes'].page = function () {
  return Meteor.Router.page();
};
```

But that didn't work, I got an error from the app saying that attributes on the body are not supported. Changing layout.html to this:

```
<head>
  <title>Meteor App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div {{> body-attributes}}>
      {{renderPage}}
  </div>
</body>

<template name="body-attributes">data-view-name="{{page}}" class="layout-container {{page}}"<template>
```

Resulted in totally broken HTML. The browser shows a '>' before the page, and the console elements panel looks like so:
[image: Console screenshots]

Why doesn't that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `{{> body-attributes}}` inside an HTML tag (in your case, the `body` tag) ultimately means that Meteor will inject a [DocumentFragment](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_render) into the DOM at that location.

For the sake of reactivity, these `DocumentFragments` are not vanilla reproductions of the markup in your template, but rather are wrapped up in special Meteoresque reactivity tags that help the backend engine keep the `Template` updated. You can see this by invoking the Template function and investigating what `_domFrag` looks like:

```
var _domFrag = Template.myTemplateName();
```

So, `Templates` in a meteor context are not designed to be embedded as attributes on HTML tags because it's injecting additional tags within the tag itself. Your second attempt is more in line with the way the framework works.

Hope that helps explain this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I'm marking yours as the answer, and will say people should check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072799/using-a-template-to-generate-html-tag-attributes-in-meteor-is-broken/14072874#14072874) to get around this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why meteor does not allow templates inside of HTML tags at the highest level, but I found a way to get around the problem. I changed layout.html to look like this:

```
<head>
  <title>Meteor App</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{> global-layout}}
</body>

<template name="global-layout">
  <div data-view-name="{{page}}" class="global-container {{page}}">
    {{renderPage}}
  </div>
</template>
```

And then switched the name from `body-attributes` to `global-layout` in layout.js. This works perfectly and solver my problem, but I would still love to know why the first option (in my question) didn't work initially.

Comment: The `<body>` tag in your template is not an actual HTML body tag - it doesn't refer to the same element. That's why it doesn't work. It's a little unintuitive but once you understand that they're two different things, it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Is that true for the head tag to? If so, how does one go about making a dynamic page title?

Comment: Just set `document.title` with Javascript. It's a bit different than you're used to, but think from Javascript out instead of from HTML out.